# why is boost::barrier wait not an interruption point?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, synchronization, interrupt-handling

Threads waiting with a boost::barrier wait() do not get interrupted when boost::thread Interrupt() is called. e.g.
http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/thread-interruption-in-boost-thread-library.html

Is there a good reason for this?

Of course we can manually place a boost::this_thread::interruption_point() to work round it.

Comment: Where exactly did you find the first sentence? It's not in the page you linked.

Comment: @Tudor: The link lists the interruption points, and that does not include `boost::barrier::wait()` (unless the implementation of it is calling `wait()` on a condition variable...)

Comment: @Tudor I didnt, I observed the behaviour and see that this page confirmed it as expected, by the fact that boost:barrier is not listed. Adding the interruption_point manually solved the issue. But I just wondered...

Comment: Possibly because barrier `wait` is a collective operation that requires all the threads to wait for eachother. If one of them is interrupted then all the others could deadlock.

Comment: That's not true. barrier::wait is implemented in terms of condition::wait and that is an interruption point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost interruption points throw exception if interruption flag has been set on current thread and the behaviour is fundamentally different than suspending the thread and calling interruption handler. Neither of locks in boost is an interruption point, which follows the behaviour of pthread locks; when pthread lock is interrupted by signal handler while waiting, it'll keep waiting when the handler is done. In the same manner, if you mark a boost thread as interrupted, `boost::mutex::lock()` or `boost::barrier::wait()` will keep waiting.

The other thing is, if you allowed `barrier::wait()` to prematurely return without acquiring the lock, you would have to unregister the current thread from the pool of threads waiting for the barrier before throwing an exception, which would make the implementation more complex. It would also allow for lock/wait methods to return without acquiring the lock, which would also make your code more complicated.

Generally, I think it's simply a design choice.

If you look at methods that are interruption points, you'll see they're usually meant to sleep for a longer time (`boost::this_thread::sleep()`, `boost::condition_variable_any::wait()`) and their conterparts `sleep` and `pthread_cond_wait` are also being terminated by signals. Although an exception here is `boost::thread::join()`, which is an interruption point, while `pthread_join` keep waiting after handling a signal.